# How is it possible to implement the drawing of the SVG circle when scrolling horizontally

Tags: css, animation, svg, scroll

I have div with width 1000px, horizontal scroll and SVG image.

[image]

I have 5 circles inside the SVG image. How is it possible to implement drawing of each circle every 20% of scrolling. I mean every scrollable div -> draw circle inside.

Like loader animation:

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozktpbw5/)

Code:

```css
.svg-circles-progress {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 200px;
}

.svg-circles-progress svg {
    max-width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 250px;
}
.horizontal-scroll {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 1000px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.horizontal-scroll .box {
  margin: 20px; 
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="draw-svg-widget">
  <div class="svg-circles-progress">
  <svg width="421" height="408" viewBox="0 0 421 408" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <ellipse cx="209" cy="207" rx="29" ry="29" transform="rotate(-180 209 207)" stroke="#BDBDBD" stroke-dasharray="4 4"/>
  <ellipse cx="209" cy="207" rx="74" ry="74" transform="rotate(-180 209 207)" stroke="#BDBDBD" stroke-dasharray="4 4"/>
  <ellipse cx="209" cy="207" rx="118" ry="118" transform="rotate(-180 209 207)" stroke="#BDBDBD" stroke-dasharray="4 4"/>
  <ellipse cx="209" cy="207" rx="162" ry="162" transform="rotate(-180 209 207)" stroke="#BDBDBD" stroke-dasharray="4 4"/>
  <ellipse cx="209" cy="207" rx="200" ry="200" transform="rotate(-180 209 207)" stroke="#BDBDBD" stroke-dasharray="4 4"/>
  <path d="M2.49982 207L2.49982 213.5L15.4998 213.5L15.4998 207L2.49982 207ZM358.637 84.3176C360.913 87.0937 365.009 87.4991 367.785 85.2231C370.561 82.947 370.966 78.8515 368.69 76.0754L358.637 84.3176ZM15.4998 207C15.4998 167.102 27.8331 128.179 50.8107 95.5619L40.183 88.0751C15.6617 122.884 2.49982 164.421 2.49982 207L15.4998 207ZM50.8107 95.5619C73.7883 62.9446 106.287 38.2275 143.856 24.7954L139.479 12.5543C99.3862 26.8888 64.7044 53.2664 40.183 88.0751L50.8107 95.5619ZM143.856 24.7954C181.425 11.3633 222.228 9.87282 260.677 20.5282L264.149 8.00034C223.116 -3.37086 179.572 -1.78029 139.479 12.5543L143.856 24.7954ZM260.677 20.5282C299.126 31.1835 333.341 53.4637 358.637 84.3176L368.69 76.0754C341.695 43.1485 305.181 19.3716 264.149 8.00034L260.677 20.5282Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
  <defs>
  <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="424.5" y1="229" x2="-211.5" y2="231" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <stop stop-color="#CE008E"/>
  <stop offset="0.512051" stop-color="#3913BA"/>
  <stop offset="0.869792" stop-color="#3913BA" stop-opacity="0"/>
  </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  </svg>
</div>

  <div class="horizontal-scroll">
    <div class="box one"> Draw Circle 1 </div>
    <div class="box two"> Draw Circle 2 </div>
    <div class="box three"> Draw Circle 3 </div>
    <div class="box four"> Draw Circle 4 </div>
    <div class="box five"> Draw Circle 5 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean to start with no circle?. Then the first circle will complete between 0 and 20%, second between 20% and 40%, third 40% to 60%, fourth 60% to 80% and fifth will end at 100%. Isn't it? Do you want the circles to be drawn whilethe user scrolls the page or want them just to appear?

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS so, i mean, i have scroll (1000px), and if i scroll right 200px -> draw 1 circle, scroll right 400px -> draw 2 circle,  scroll right 600px -> draw 3 circle, scroll right 800px -> draw 4 circle and scroll right 1000px -> draw 5 circle.

Comment: But, What do you mean by draw? Just render the whole circle at once or make the path to draw as the scroll advaces?

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS yes, draw as the scroll advaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use javascript to achieve what you want.

Here's an example of how to do that.  I've commented the code, so hopefully you can follow along with what it is doing.

```js
// The div that scrolls
var scroller = document.querySelector(".horizontal-scroll-container");
// The five progress circles
var progressCircles = document.querySelectorAll(".progress-circles circle");

scroller.addEventListener("scroll", function(evt) {
  // Calculate the percentage that the user has scrolled. The result is a value between 0 and 1.
  //   scrollLeft is the scroll offset of the contents of .horizontal-scroll-container
  //   scrollWidth is the width of the contents of .horizontal-scroll-container
  //   offsetWidth is the width that is visible in the scroll region 
  let scrollFraction = evt.target.scrollLeft / (evt.target.scrollWidth - evt.target.offsetWidth);
  // For each of the progress circles, draw the fraction of the circumference based
  // on how far through the scroll we are.
  let rangeForEachCircle = 1 / progressCircles.length;
  progressCircles.forEach(function(ellipseElem, index) {
    let circleStart = index * rangeForEachCircle;
    setDashArray(ellipseElem, circleStart, rangeForEachCircle, scrollFraction);
  });
});

function setDashArray(circleElem, fractionStart, fractionRange, scrollFraction)
{
  let circleRadius = circleElem.r.baseVal.value;
  let circleCircumference = Math.PI * 2 * circleRadius;
  let dashFraction = (scrollFraction - fractionStart) / fractionRange;
  // If dashFraction is less than 0, then scroll hasn't reached this circle yet.
  // Clamp dash length to 0 (no dash shown).
  dashFraction = Math.max(dashFraction, 0);
  // If dashFraction is greater than 1, then we have passed this circle.
  // Clamp dash length to 1 (full circle shown).
  dashFraction = Math.min(dashFraction, 1)
  // Calculate and set the circle's dash pattern
  let dashLength = dashFraction * circleCircumference;
  circleElem.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", dashLength + " " + circleCircumference);
}
```

```css
.svg-circles-progress {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 200px;
}

.svg-circles-progress svg {
    max-width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 250px;
}

.horizontal-scroll-container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.horizontal-scroll {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.horizontal-scroll .box {
  margin: 20px; 
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="draw-svg-widget">
  <div class="svg-circles-progress">
  <svg width="421" height="408" viewBox="0 0 421 408" fill="none">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="424.5" y1="229" x2="-211.5" y2="231" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop stop-color="#CE008E"/>
        <stop offset="0.512051" stop-color="#3913BA"/>
        <stop offset="0.869792" stop-color="#3913BA" stop-opacity="0"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <!-- grey circles -->
    <g stroke="#BDBDBD">
      <ellipse cx="209" cy="207" rx="29" ry="29"/>
      <ellipse cx="209" cy="207" rx="74" ry="74"/>
      <ellipse cx="209" cy="207" rx="118" ry="118"/>
      <ellipse cx="209" cy="207" rx="162" ry="162"/>
      <ellipse cx="209" cy="207" rx="200" ry="200"/>
    </g>
    <!-- coloured circles -->
    <g class="progress-circles" transform="rotate(-180 209 207)"
      stroke="url(#paint0_linear)" stroke-width="16" stroke-dasharray="0, 1000">
      <circle cx="209" cy="207" r="200"/>
      <circle cx="209" cy="207" r="162"/>
      <circle cx="209" cy="207" r="118"/>
      <circle cx="209" cy="207" r="74"/>
      <circle cx="209" cy="207" r="29"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="horizontal-scroll-container">
  <div class="horizontal-scroll">
    <div class="box one"> Draw Circle 1 </div>
    <div class="box two"> Draw Circle 2 </div>
    <div class="box three"> Draw Circle 3 </div>
    <div class="box four"> Draw Circle 4 </div>
    <div class="box five"> Draw Circle 5 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's amazing solution!